# @font-face Blacklisted font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've been using font-squirrel for quite sometime and was really happy with its generator and the @font-face method as it doesn't produce any FOUT. But recently a project came for development and when I tried to generate, it gave an error

> The font abc.otf is blacklisted by the
>   Generator. Sorry

Where abc.otf is font-file. Now the client has purchased the license for the font, only issue is while development I don't know how to use the font. I don't want to use Cufon as it doesn't support change in styling and I need to have different color for Hover text.

I am looking for a website which can generate @font-face variants for IE7+ {EOT}, firefox and webkit

Comment: What kind of license has your client purchased? Does the license explicitly cover redistribution through `font-face` type services? Because AFAIK most standard licenses don't. Also see this re blacklisting policy: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/12/how-to-use-the-generator

Comment: thanks for the link, and sorry I don't have knowledge about kind of license they have purchased. But my job is to slice the design into html/css. The font was provided to me by the client when I requested that its a non-standard font.

Comment: Cufon does support changes in styling, well unless you mean dynamic changes in which case you are correct.

Comment: @Ian.. any way out? Right now I have an option to regenerate cufon each time a hover or change in style occurs..

Comment: Note also that in most cases it isn't particularly legal for your client to just give you a copy of the font. The same foundries who ask Font Squirrel to not generate web fonts from their desktop fonts tend to have licenses that don't allow people to just give the fonts to folks doing work for them....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it :)

http://www.font2web.com/

Comment: it worked, but did not create a woff version

Comment: also try http://www.font-face-generator.com/

Comment: font2web is broken right now..

Comment: font-face-generator.com link isn't working.

Comment: Did not convert my font...

Comment: Converted ttf successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a TTF to EOT converter I found (Its online and free!)

http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi

There is also Microsoft's WEFT tool:

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/web/embedding/weft3/download.aspx

Hope this sorts your problem.

**UPDATE:**

http://www.freefontconverter.com/ - Every format you'll ever need.

Comment: thanks for the link, but EOT is only for IE... I would want to make svg and otf as well from my ttf file for gecko and webkit

Comment: @Tarun - see above for ttf to ~ everything converter

Comment: http://www.freefontconverter.com/ is good enough but when to write the style sheet, you can based on fontsquirrel style or google web font; for some unicode character better to provide unicode range for the font