# Fonts - generated font doesn't work in ie?

Tags: css, fonts

I have generated a font named ( Futura Std Light ) in this website (www.font2web.com) but the font doesn't work in ie.

I was generating my fonts in (www.fontsquirrel.com) and they work better in ie but the problem here is that this font is in the blacklist.

Any ideas, please ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905932/font-face-blacklisted-font

Answer (score 0):

It is not meant to work in browsers; it has been blacklisted for a reason: using the font as a web font is a copyright infringement.

Consider using a suitable free font instead, or some other font that you may legally use.